# Hide a Row depending on cells values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to Hide a Row if the values in multiple cells are equal to 0. I have tried this VBA code, it “works” but at the end the rows with 0 are not being hidden.

```
Sub Rehien_ausblenden()
    Dim i As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("Daten").Activate
    For i = 12 To 45
        If Cells(i, 7).Value = 0 And Cells(i, 8).Value = 0 _
        And Cells(i, 9).Value = 0 And Cells(i, 10).Value Then
          Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
        MsgBox ("Completed")
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`And Cells(i, 10).Value Then` is probably missing `= 0` ? Please check if `And Cells(i, 10).Value = 0 Then` works.

Further I recommend the following changes:

- Avoid using `.Activate` and use a `With` statement instead (You might benefit from reading
  [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)).
- Use `Long` instead of `Integer`: There is no benefit in using `Integer` in VBA ([Why Use Integer Instead of Long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520)) but you easily run into errors using `Integer` for row counting because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.

Note that your code only hides rows but never unhides anything. So if you run this multiple times any hidden row will always stay hidden, even if the `if` statement is not true anymore.

```
Sub Rehien_ausblenden()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Daten")
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 12 To 45
            If .Cells(i, 7).Value = 0 And .Cells(i, 8).Value = 0 _
               And .Cells(i, 9).Value = 0 And .Cells(i, 10).Value = 0 Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    MsgBox "Completed"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As mention by Ren, you indeed need to correct your code as follows:

```
        If Cells(i, 7).Value = 0 And Cells(i, 8).Value = 0 _
        And Cells(i, 9).Value = 0 And Cells(i, 10).Value = 0 Then
```

(add  `= 0` at cell in column 10)

In addition, I'd like to inform you that not filling in a value in a cell also results in the cell value being zero: in my case I had only filled in value 0 in row 12, all the rest was blank but still all rows, from 12 up to 45, are hidden.